# Spring - getting bean at runtime with custom qualifier

Tags: java, spring

I created a custom Spring `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Target({
        ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.METHOD,
        ElementType.PARAMETER, 
        ElementType.TYPE,
        ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Database {
    String value() default "";
}
```

I then applyed this annotation to the various implementing Beans:

```
@Repository
@Database("mysql")
class MySqlActionRepository implements ActionRepository {}

@Repository
@Database("oracle")
class OracleActionRepository implements ActionRepository {}

@Repository
@Database("sqlserver")
class SqlServerActionRepository implements ActionRepository {}
```

Now, being that at runtime, only one of these Beans has to be available for injection, I created a `@Primary` Bean method.

```
@Bean
@Primary
ActionRepository actionRepository(
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext,
        final Configuration configuration) {
    final var database = configuration.getString("...");
    return BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(
            applicationContext,
            ActionRepository.class,
            database
    );
}
```

However this solution **does not** work with my custom annotation. It works only when using the standard `@Qualifier` one.

Any idea how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem that from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13532?jql=text%2520~%2520%2522BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils%2522#issuecomment-453363699) , `BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils` does not support your case . But we can combine  `ApplicationContext` 's `getBeansOfType()` and `findAnnotationOnBean()` to achieve the same purpose :

```
@Bean
@Primary
ActionRepository actionRepository(final ApplicationContext applicationContext,
        final Configuration configuration) {
    final var database = configuration.getString("...");

    Map<String, ActionRepository> beanMap = context.getBeansOfType(ActionRepository.class);

    for (Map.Entry<String, ActionRepository> entry : beanMap.entrySet()) {
        Database db = context.findAnnotationOnBean(entry.getKey(), Database.class);
        if (db != null && db.value().equals(database)) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find the bean...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. Seems a "good" solution. I say good not because it's your fault, but because having to manually check the annotation value is error-prone. I don't know if you know a bit of CDI, but with CDI the bean selection is like... awesome.